# Can I change the GDAL/OGR library that QGIS uses?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, windows

I have been adding a new format to OGR, all seems well and OGRInfo works. Now I would like to test my code out using QGIS. Is there an easy way to switch which GDAL lib QGIS uses on a windows box? I've read [Tim's blog post](http://linfiniti.com/2011/09/building-gdal-under-windows-with-all-the-bells-whistles/) but would rather not go down the recompiling from source route if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This weekend I added a new OGR driver dll to the OSGeo4W build. You can drop a new gdal plugin - as long as it matches the same gdal version (in my case 1.8 - QGIS picked it up without trouble).

Comment: did you just copy the dll in or were other files needed to?

Comment: just my new dll and an extra non-gdal dll that I was using for my driver. I can read and write filegdbs from my QGIS without a problem - no changes needed from their end

Comment: can you tell me where you added your new dll as I can't seem to find the right spot.

Comment: I cannot remember the exact location since I did it on a different machine that I do not have access to... but you can just download OSGeo4W, install qgis, and under the advanced section of the installer you will find a filegdb ogr driver. Search for files called filegdb - you should only find two - and those are the two places where I added them...

Answer (score 1):

I asked exactly the same question some time on the qgis mailing list, and here is the [reply](http://osdir.com/ml/qgis-user-gis/2011-10/msg00126.html)

To quote from it

```
I just have to make sure that my gdal shared object has the same name (or
creates a symlink) as the one expected by QGIS (libgdal1.6.0.so.1 in my case),
and add in LD_LIBRARY_PATH the name of the directory with this custom build.
```

Also: if you install the gdaltools plugin, you can specify the gdal binary to be used for this plugin - it would be great, if QGIS would have the same functionality build in.

Comment: sadly I'm stuck on a windows box for this project so I don't have an LD_LIBRARY_PATH (I think).