# Installing QGIS 2.0 with the newest gdal and geos libraries

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, geos, compile

I want to install QGIS 2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I followed these [steps](http://www.digital-geography.com/install-qgis-2-0-on-ubuntu/) until the final installation command.

Before I compiled gdal 1.10, geos 3.4.2 and grass 6.4.3 on my own.

In the synaptic package manager I marked qgis (2.0.1-2+precise1) for installation and I can see that the older libraries gdal 1.7, geos 3.3.8 are marked as well.

How can I build QGIS with the new compiled libraries?? I want to avoid that the old libraries will be installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to install QGIS with apt-get, instead of synaptic with

```
    sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
```

following with:

```
    sudo apt-get install qgis-plugin-grass
```

to get the grass plugin, as shown [here](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu) (similar to your link, but the official QGIS guide).

This should, as far as I know, recognise the GDAL version (1.10 in your case) already installed on your machine.

For the GRASS installation (6 or 7), to make sure all the relevant dependencies are running, a good guide is given on the [grasswiki: Compile and Install Ubuntu](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu) page.

[This Linfiniti blog post](http://linfiniti.com/2009/11/compiling-qgis-under-ubuntu-9-10/) is an older guide on installing QGIS from source, if the above apt-get suggestion does not work, and 
[this: Can I change the GDAL/OGR library that QGIS uses?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15975/can-i-change-the-gdal-ogr-library-that-qgis-uses) seem to be another related post.